# How do i forecast a time series is about to cross a certain threshold

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, model

I have data coming in 10 seconds apart which is the temperature of a given room. It has a seasonality of 6 hours as it has 2 AC switching back and forth. Sometimes the AC in this room fails and thus it will push the temperature up to a given threshold and sends out an alert.

I would like to create an algorithm to give an early detection alert with a confidence percentage as soon as it can. I have contemplated monitoring the rate of change of temperature for every 3 minutes (18 observation) and summing up the rate of change to see if it exceeds a certain percentage of the average sum of rate of change. Is this a good way to go? But i have no confidence percentage this way. Are there any more simple or more complex solutions? Many thanks :)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3382%20threshold suggesting a mojnte-carlo approcah to get prediction intervals i.e a distribution of forecasts for each period in the future.

Comment: thank you @IrishStat , from what i understand is that i have to create a forecast model and use monte carlo to generate random points generated by said model to get the confidence level? Can i use tbats model for this purpose?

Comment: No that is not a feature of Tbats . AUTOBOX (which I helped to develop) is the only commercially available solution that I am aware of and there is no "free software" to perform this"magic"..